# Force Chrome Developer Tools to open in its own tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I have the following afflictions:

1. I code on a netbook and
2. I don't like to have to leave a single browser window.

Generally, this creates no problems; I have Chrome's Secure Shell loaded in one tab to access vim and the page I'm working on in a tab next to it.  When I go to use Developer Tools, however, I either have to dock it to the page (not good on a netbook) or open it in a new window (not desired).

Does anyone know of a way to get DT to open in its own tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid that’s not currently possible/supported. You’ll notice that if you right-click on the titlebar of an undocked DT window, the *Show as tab* option is disabled. Further, dragging the window around does not trigger any of the typical docking or window-merging functions because a DT window is somewhat specially handled.

You could theoretically hack the menu to enable it, but that would likely result in undefined/unpredictable behavior. You could also compile your own version of Chromium if you are up to it, but your best bet is to just [request it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) since it does not seem to have been brought up yet (the [closest reported issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154199) is about docking to the right which was closed).